# Large int on checkedId setoncheckedchangeListener

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

Whenever I receive the id from the checkedId, it's a really long int for example (2131034187) even if I have declared an id for every radiobutton in the xml file. I have no idea what causes this or how to fix it. Here's my code.

XML layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Java class

```
holder.rbg = (RadioGroup)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.rbg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                Log.d("id", checkedId+"");
                 selections[position] = checkedId;
            }
});
```

Error log

```
11-27 12:20:37.701: D/AbsListView(8560): unregisterIRListener() is called 
11-27 12:20:37.711: D/AbsListView(8560): unregisterIRListener() is called 
11-27 12:20:37.756: D/AbsListView(8560): unregisterIRListener() is called 
11-27 12:20:37.791: D/AbsListView(8560): unregisterIRListener() is called 
11-27 12:20:37.916: D/AbsListView(8560): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
11-27 12:20:37.916: D/AbsListView(8560): unregisterIRListener() is called 
11-27 12:20:38.921: D/id(8560): 2131034186
11-27 12:20:49.491: D/id(8560): 2131034188
```

Comment: use tags to achive this (what are u to do can u explain )

Comment: Right now my Ids are 10 chars long, but I want them to be 1 char long. I'll add my Error log to show what I mean.

Comment: do you want position of the radio button checked and behave accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id's are generated in R.java is the dynamically generated class, created during build process to dynamically identify all assets (from strings to android widgets to layouts), for usage in java classes in Android app.

This class has all the id's of the view and is cannot be made 1 char long.

Hope this helps.